# Simplest way to ship Julia with precompiled packages

Tags: julia

I plan to use Julia in my applied maths class but in order to improve the student user experience during the first lab session, I would like to provide them a Julia version with precompiled packages (Plots.jl, DifferentialEquations.jl, namely) under macOS, Linux and Windows. Part of the answer I need is here: https://julialang.org/blog/2021/01/precompile_tutorial/ but I am missing some platform specific guidelines in order to seemlessly integrate the compiled packages in the application bundle.

Comment: That precompile tutorial is more low-level detail than you want, I think this sort of stuff is what PackageCompiler.jl does, but I'm not sure because I never had to use it.

Comment: That blog post is directed more at developers than users. Modern versions of OrdinaryDifferentialEquations already have vastly lower latency (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/22-seconds-to-3-and-now-more-lets-fix-all-of-the-differentialequations-jl-universe-compile-times/66313) thanks to changes like those described in the blog post, but there's nothing you have to do to "activate" them except be on recent package versions. If that's still insufficient, then PackageCompiler is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. With current stable Julia version (1.6.3) and a not so old computer (Mac Mini 2012) it took several minutes (more than five) to compile DifferentialEquations.jl, but since my course starts in mach 2022 timings should improve until then.

Answer (score 0):

The [blog post on SciML compile times](https://sciml.ai/news/2022/09/21/compile_time/) shows how the full images of the packages are now generated by default using snoop precompilation. Thus the creation of fully contained precompiled packages just requires shipping a built system image, which can be done with PackageCompiler.jl. As the blog post shows, this is done with the command:

```
using PackageCompiler
create_sysimage(["DifferentialEquations"], sysimage_path="DiffEqSysImage.so")
```

and will also eliminate JIT lag on anything that's in the precompile statement. This can be further modified by supplying a precompile execution file, as is [described in the PackageCompiler.jl documentation](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/stable/examples/plots.html).